# Azure Kubernetes - Customized Name for the Extra Resource group created as a part of the AKS Setup?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created an instance of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and have discovered that apart from the resource group I created the AKS instance in, one more resource group is created for me.

Eg:

My AKS Resource Group: Production_MyAKSInstance
Additional Resource Group: MC_MyResourceGroup-Production_MyAKSInstance_westeurope

Is there a way to rename the Additional Resource Group something like Production_MyAKSInstance_Supportive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rename it however you can specify a name when you create the cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq

> By default, AKS will name the node resource group
> MC_resourcegroupname_clustername_location, but you can also provide
> your own name.
>
> To specify your own resource group name, install the aks-preview Azure
> CLI extension version 0.3.2 or later. When you create an AKS cluster
> by using the az aks create command, use the --node-resource-group
> parameter and specify a name for the resource group. If you use an
> Azure Resource Manager template to deploy an AKS cluster, you can
> define the resource group name by using the nodeResourceGroup
> property.
>
> The secondary resource group is automatically created by the Azure
> resource provider in your own subscription. You can specify a custom
> resource group name only when you're creating the cluster. As you work
> with the node resource group, keep in mind that you cannot:
>
> Specify an existing resource group for the node resource group.
> Specify a different subscription for the node resource group. Change
> the node resource group name after the cluster has been created.
> Specify names for the managed resources within the node resource
> group. Modify or delete Azure-created tags of managed resources within
> the node resource group.

Comment: Did this parameter vanish in a later version? I'm using Azure CLI AKS Extension 0.5.58 and it is not available anymore.